# Can Laravel's Eloquent update a creation time but not an update time?

Tags: laravel, timestamp, eloquent

I'm presently learning Laravel and Eloquent, and have set up some initial migrations to play with. One of my tables only needs a creation time, since once a row is inserted there, it will never be updated:

```
    // The run table only needs a creation timestamp, not an updated timestamp
    Schema::create('runs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamp('created_at');
    });
```

I understand that Eloquent by default expects both a `created_at` and an `updated_at` column to be present, and that this feature can be turned off entirely. From the manual:

> By default, Eloquent expects created_at and updated_at columns to exist on your tables. If you do not wish to have these columns automatically managed by Eloquent, set the `$timestamps` property on your model to false.

However, is it possible for Eloquent to be asked to automatically set a creation time and not an update time? I realise I can do this manually, but it would be nice if Eloquent could do this "for free".

Comment: [A simple solution](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18067614), which I am using for now, is to set the default column value at the database level, and turn off the timestamp feature in Eloquent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

I had a look at `framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php` which handles the timestamps and it's not directly possible.

You could override a bunch of methods to make it work:

- `public function setUpdatedAt($value)`
- anywhere there's a reference to `static::UPDATED_AT`
- anywhere that depends on the value of `usesTimestamps()`
- and certainly other places

At best, this would be vulnerable to future code changes so I don't recommend it.

Comment: A nice straightforward answer, for which thanks! No problem - I'll stick with the manual approach.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use

```php
$model->touch();
```

Comment: Would that not fail if the `updated_at` column is missing?