# obtaining the current timestamp in mysql in Valetina studio

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, valentina-studio

I am learnig **laravel** from **Laracast videos** and using **Valentina Studio** as GUI to have a look at the database and connect using mysql . I have composer and mariadb installed on linux.
so, when I was creating a new field in an empty table which has created_at and updated_at as columns, I used NOW() expecting that it would take the current timestamp. But it(valentina studio) shows

```
>  " Error (1292) 22007: Incorrect datetime value: 'now()' for column 'created_at' at row 1"
```

Ps: I have looked at others answers related to timestamps in mysql,  but I believe I may be missing something related to Valentina studio commands.

Comment: Few days ago, it took that command NOW() and was displaying 0000-00-00 00:00:00. How do I make it take the exact current time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the link, although for `created_at` and `updated_at` you can just use `$table->timestamps();`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20822267/2419954

Answer (score 0):

Change `NOW()` to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`

Comment: @Nitz your create table via migration?)

Comment: Yes.I did ' php artisan migrate '  Also the main question is, will the valentina studio field box take these sql commands correctly or is there any other command specific to valentina studio to get the timestamp ?