# Laravel's useCurrent() doesn't work when a record is updated in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have recently added a new migration to my database which in its simplest form does something like this

```
If(Schema::hasTable('some_table')){
    Schema::table('some_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dateTime('last_updated')->nullable(false)->useCurrent()->change();
    });
}
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20822267/6547573) on SE, Laravel should automatically create and updated the last_record column for me but I am testing this in MySQL 5.7.31 and this is definitely not the case for me. I am using Laravel 7.5 and my PHP version is 7.3.21.

Meanwhile, adding `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` manually to my database failed as well. So, it seems that it might be an issue with my MySQL database instead of Laravel itself. So, I have two questions:

Is it possible to somehow use Laravel/PHP to always add a default value to a field when nothing is passed on insert or update?

Edit: @lagbox asked about how I am saving/updating records in my database. Here is how

```
$record= TableModel::where('blah', $blah)
                ->first();

if($record){
    $record->update([
         'blah1' => $blah1,
         'blah2' => $blah2
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Eloquent will automatically handle `created_at` and `updated_at`

Comment: @lagbox Yes, but my field is `last_updated`, not `updated_at`. Is it possible to tell Eloquent to change the default name?

Comment: yes if you check `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` you will see `const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';` so you can define that on your Model as you like    https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions Model Conventions - Timestamps

Comment: @lagbox Thank you. I'm sorry if there's something really trivial that I'm missing, but I added ```const UPDATED_AT = 'last_updated';``` to my model for my table, but it's still not working. :|

Comment: how are you saving/updating this record?

Comment: @lagbox I added how I am updating my record. I am basically calling update on my model which extends ```Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model```.

Comment: you didn't set `$timestamps = false;` on the model did you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the fields that are used for the `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamps on the Model that Eloquent will automatically handle:

```
const UPDATED_AT = 'last_updated';
```

You can also disable a particular timestamp by setting the `const` to `null`:

```
const CREATED_AT = null;
```

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Eloquent - Model Conventions - Timestamps](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) `UPDATED_AT` `CREATED_AT`