# Object of class Illuminate\Support\Facades\Date could not be converted to string

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-7, laravel-migrations

I am having this error after upgrading my project from laravel 7 to laravel 8 could someone explain it to me coz the project;s migrations were working well but now I can not run artisan migrate

```
     $table->date('booked_from')->default(new Date());
        $table->date('booked_to')->default(new Date());
```

Comment: The error msg seems pretty clear?  `default()` expects a string, presumably something like `2021-05-29 01:02:03` or whatever, but `new Date()` is an Illuminate\Support\Facades\Date object.  If you just want to give it today's date, you could simply use `date('Y-m-d')` or some other format?

Comment: I wanted to pick the current date when an insertion is made just like mysql's current timestamp works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to one of the many solutions provide in the question [Don't Panic provides in his comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067614/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-of-a-timestamp-column-to-the-current-timestamp-w), you can also leverage the [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) DateTime package which comes with Laravel.

```php
$table->date('booked_from'->default(Carbon::now());
$table->date('booked_to')->default(Carbon::now());
```